# How can I conditionally call attributes within ActiveRecord's where?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a piece of code that looks something like:

```
foreign_object = (some_test) ? nil : <some foreign_object>

Document.where(foreign_id: foreign_object, status: "Working", ... )
```

If foreign_object is nil, It will only find Documents with foreign_id = NULL. Is there a way to conditionally put the foreign_id in? I essentially want to write:

```
Document.where(foreign_id: foreign_object if foreign_object, status: "Working", ...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do this in such cases:

```
 documents = Document.where(status: 'working')
 documents = documents.where(foreign_id: foreign_object) if foreign_object
```

Comment: There is no other way, BTW :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit: Well, one could build params hash and call `where` one time, but yes, this is essentially the same thing.

Comment: Don't you guys ever sleep?!?

Comment: @BradWerth: preparing for the sleep mode. Just some customary late night stackoverflowing :)